# how can I have multiple values for a drop down list under a single variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a simple form with chosen as jquery library.  I require that the input values are in a single variable idb as they are utilized later in a regex expression on that variable.  Currently the way it works is that they are placed in separate variables idb like this: &idb=02&idb=03&idb=04 and I want them to appear like this: idb=05%2C+06%2C+07.

here is my code:

```
<form action="./index.html" method="GET">
Device Id: <select data-placeholder="Input here device id" multiple class="chosen-select" name="idb">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option>01</option>
        <option>02</option>
        <option>03</option>
        <option>04</option>
        <option>05</option>
        <option>06</option>
        <option>07</option>
        <option>08</option>
      </select>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
  </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $('.chosen-select').chosen({}).change( function(obj, result) {
        console.debug("changed: %o", arguments);

        console.log("selected: " + result.selected);
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: I don't understand how it would bring multiple values in the first place. Your `select` tag does not define (unless I'm missing something) the `multiple` attribute.

Comment: You are missing it. It's in the OP, and control+click will allow multiple selections as shown in the answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get your expected output by using a hidden input that stores the value for you.
You just need to listen for the `change` event on the `<select />` and update the hidden input accordingly.

Short example:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.chosen-select').chosen({}).change(function() {
    let selectedOptions = [].slice.call(this.selectedOptions);
    let optionValues = selectedOptions.map(o => o.value);
    $(".idb").val(optionValues.join(","));
  });

  // to show the output in demo, remove this
  $('form').submit(function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    console.log($('form').serialize());
  });
});
```

```css
.chosen-select { width: 300px; }
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/chosen-js@1.8.7/chosen.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/chosen-js@1.8.7/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>

<form action="./index.html" method="GET">
  Device Id:
  <input type="hidden" value="" name="idb" class="idb" />
  <select data-placeholder="Input here device id" multiple class="chosen-select">
    <option value="" hidden></option>
    <option>01</option>
    <option>02</option>
    <option>03</option>
    <option>04</option>
    <option>05</option>
    <option>06</option>
    <option>07</option>
    <option>08</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" value="Wyślij" />
</form>
```

If you want the result as an array rather then a comma-separated string, you could try using `idb[]` instead of `idb` as the input name.
(If your backend supports this)

Comment: Thanks for reply.  I tried your code and it breaks the chosen into a standard drop down list (which is not what I want).  Moreover Submit button stopped working.  If you can help me I'd be grateful.

Comment: @aretai you need to remove the form submit handler from my code for the submit button to actually submit something, i just added it for the demo.

Comment: @aretai to get the autocomplete box again instead of a regular dropdown you need to call `.chosen({})` on `$('.chosen-select')`

Comment: Thanks for reply.  I have removed the form submit handler and the submit button works.  However it doesn't get any values for idb (i.e. idb values are empty).  I have also called .chosen{} on $('.chosen-select'), but with no success (i.e. list is still dropdown).  My code below.

Comment: @aretai I updarted my answer to include `chosen-js` which i assume is what you're using. You should be getting a value for `idb`. Please note that the `<select>` does **not** have a name set, only the `<input type="hidden">` has the name `idb`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I included the same libraries as you and it is working now.  The problem now is that I'm getting only the first value for idb and it is appearing after the first empty idb (so for example ?idb=&idb=03).  Additionally when I hit the back button in my browser and don't add any more values for idb and then hit Submit again I get empty idb like this ?idb=&idb=.

Comment: Update.  The values appear correctly (so not only the single value for idb) but after the first empty idb so: ?idb=&idb=02%2C03%2C06

Comment: @aretai did you remove the `name="idb"` from the `<select>`? Were you using a different library? I just assumed your `.chosen()` came from the jquery plugin `chosen-js`, so I added it to the snippet

Comment: Yes I removed the name="idb" from the select.  I used the chosen library, but from a different source.  I changed to your source and it worked.  Thanks for all the help.

Comment: @aretai np, glad i can help :) Do you have any additional elements on the site with `name="idb"` that might cause that duplication?

Comment: ahh yes just spotted another element with name="idb". Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
  $('.chosen-select').chosen({}).change(function(el) {
    let selectedOptions = [].slice.call(this.selectedOptions);
    let optionValues = selectedOptions.map(o => o.value);
    $(".idb").val(optionValues.join(","));
  });

  // to show the output
  $('form').submit(function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    console.log($('form').serialize());
  });
});
```

Comment: you need to remove the entire `$('form').submit();` call. `$('.chosen-select').chosen({})` did work for me (using `chosen-js`, not sure what you're using)

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I have removed the entire $('form').submit(); call and it is working now.